# How to get the max range of IntWritable in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a way to get the range of `Intwritable`?

Is there something equivalent to `Int.MAX_VALUE` for `IntWritable`?

Comment: `new IntWritable(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` does not work for you?

Comment: Kindly check my answer and upvote/accept if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` is a wrapper on primitive `int` data type which makes it eligible to be used as key/value in java `map`. But `IntWritable` does not truly represents a wrapper to a primitive data type. Rather it is a variant of integer with optimized serialization implementation (java default serialization is too bulky). By saying so, `Intwritable` is not meant to replace what `Integer` is used for. Even in a mapper, common logic is written using `Integer`; it is only when you emit a value within `mapredcue` phases, the `IntWritable` type comes into picture for optimization.
Hence, it happily allow you to initialize the `IntWritable` with max value taken from anywhere, or from core java library itself:

```
 IntWritable writable = new IntWritable(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

Here it is important that it is not same as initializing an `Integer`, which returns an immutable `Integer` object. `IntWritable` do have a `set(int value)` method and is mutable. This is specifically important to support lean serialization/de-serialization.